# convex function homogeneous subadditivity

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone show me how to prove that a homogenous function $( f( cx)=cf(x) )$ is convex if and only if it is subadditive, with $f$ the function being  non-decreasing, and such that $f(0)=0.$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be convex if and only if it's subadditive? Also, what space is $f$ defined on? You say $f$ is non-decreasing, which suggests $f$ is defined on $\Bbb{R}$, but then $f(cx) = cf(x)$ would imply $f$ is linear pretty easily.

Comment: yes sorry for the mistake. How to prove that a function  ( from R to R) is convex if and only if it is subadditive.

Comment: With f being homogenous and non decreasing

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. If $f(cx) = cf(x)$ for all $x, c \in \Bbb{R}$, then $f(x) = ax$, where $a = f(1)$. This is a linear function which is (sub)additive and convex, always.

Comment: what ?? what do you mean by "then f(x)=ax"

Comment: you can have function that is f(ax)=af(x) but there are not linear ...

Comment: @MinkowskiYaacov Not for functions on $\Bbb{R}$, you can't. If $f$ is such a function, then $f(x) = f(x \cdot 1) = xf(1) = ax$, where $a$ is the constant $f(1)$. If $f$ were a function on a higher dimensional space, this would be a different story.

Comment: From the statements, I cannot clearly separate the conditions for iff directions, but it seems that the linearity is not necessary from my derivation for $x,y\ge0$: 
\begin{align}
f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)&\iff f'(x)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}\le\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(y)}{y}=f'(0)\\
&\iff f''(x)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f'(y)-f'(0)}{y}\le0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be homogeneous (of degree 1), i.e., with the property $$f(ax)=af(x)\quad \text{for all }a\in\mathbb{R},~x\in X\qquad (1)$$ 
and subadditive, i.e., with the property 
$$f(x+y)\leq f(x)+f(y)\quad \text{for all }x,y\in X.\qquad (2)$$

**Suggestions**

*$\Rightarrow$ direction:* You want to show that $f$ is also convex, i.e., that 
$$f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)\leq \alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y)\quad\text{for all }\alpha\in[0,1],~x,y\in X\qquad (3)$$

I think it is pretty easy to get there through using the definitions ((1) and (2) above). You just need to construct $f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)$ and verify that it is not greater than the right-hand side.

*$\Leftarrow$ direction:* You want to show that if (3) and (1) hold, then (2) also holds. Just pick the right value for $\alpha$. Then use homogeneity.

*Hint:* $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are multiplied by the same number (1, that is) in (2).